# How to firmly secure hdd caddy in its bay?

Tags: hard-drive, dvd, asus-laptop

My question is how to firmly secure a HDD Caddy in the ODD bay.

I have an Asus X550VX which is sold both with and without a DVD drive. Mine is without but the bay and SATA is of course there so it just a matter of replacing the plastic placeholder with a HDD caddy.

This is the BEFORE picture. Note how whatever is in the bay is secured with a screw (when I took the picture I forgot the actual screw).

[image: before install of HDD Caddy]

... and here's the AFTER picture where I've installed the HDD Caddy:
[image]
(Yes, the disk is not there but that's not the point)

So how do I secure the caddy when it doesn't have any means of doing so at its rear end ? I bought the caddy from hddcaddy.com and they claim in their video that securing the caddy with the screw is optional. From previous experience I know that these caddies will drop out of the bay if they are not secured.

Comment: Contact hddcaddy.com and ask?

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths.  I did contact them - got a swift response - and they said to use whatever I could scrape off the existing ODD drive ... which doesn't exist. Alternatively if no ODD but only a plastic dummy then re-use the metal mount from the plastic dummy. Again this doesn't exist so cannot use that advice. For the record: swift response from their support and their website never says that the caddy would work if no existing ODD, but also doesn't say the opposite. I'm perfectly willing to accept that I'm on my own here.

Comment: Why is my question so horrible that it deserves a downvote ? Please comment -- whoever you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played with various options. I cut out a piece of the plastic (from the plastic dummy drive) but it wouldn't fit. I evaluated [Techie007's response](https://superuser.com/a/1091814/487848) but don't have the tools required.

So I ended up with a very low level solution which is to place a small screw between the caddy and the metal frame of the bay:

[image]

This seems to provide sufficient resistance so that the drive is firmly locked in the bay. This solution is not general - it will surely not be appropriate in any scenario and some caution should be exercised so that you do not break or bend anything. Still it was the best I could come up with given my restrictions. Works for me, so to speak.

**Side note:**
After installation everything works fine and Samsung Magician software shows my SDD is connected to a SATA III port which is what I hoped for. (sometimes the ODD bay will only give you SATA II).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Drill a small small hole in the caddy near where lock screw hole on the chassis is, then [tap it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U5QU_3qUigk) with a [tap and die set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tap_and_die) to add threads (match the hole/thread size to a small, flat-headed screw you have).

[image]

Then use a thin piece of metal (or plastic) and screw one end into the existing lock hole, and the other end to the hole you just made in the caddy.

[image]

Comment: Wauw, I really dig how you have edited my photos to make your point. Question is of course where I would get hold of these things?  Even getting hold of that thin piece of metal isn't that easy.

Comment: Although I had to take a different - less elegant - route because of lack of tools I'm still giving you an upvote for this high quality answer. Thanks.